# Modify DTO properties with decorator

Tags: node.js, nestjs

```
export class MyDto extends Base{
@ApiModelProperty()
@Expose()
@MyCustomModifier()
readonly code: string = "";



MyCustomModifier(){
   // modify 
    code = someUpdateOnCode()
}
```

Can we do something like this, so we can update dto properties

Comment: You can perform additional data transformation using the @Transform() decorator. read the doc please before asking.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization

Answer (score 1):

```js
@Injectable()
export class JoiValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly schema) {}

  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const { error } = this.schema.validate(value);
    if (error) {
      console.log(error, 'error');
      throw new BadRequestException(error.message);
    }
    // some changing value.code = someUpdateOnCode()
    return value;
  }
}
```

and use your pipe like this

```js
import * as Joi from '@hapi/joi';
@Put('')
@UsePipes(
    new JoiValidationPipe(
        Joi.object().keys({
            code: Joi.string()
                .min(3)
                .max(250)
                .allow('')
                .optional()
        )
    })
  async someControler(){}
```

Comment: Transform(transformFn: (value: any, obj: any, transformationType: TransformationType) => any, options?: TransformOptions): (target: any, key: string) => void;
turns out, I there is a built in decorator.